# Perl: Regular Expression for finding first occurence per line? (EditPad)

Tags: regex

I am using EditPad, but generally Perl regular expression work for it. I am trying to find only the first occurrence of a pattern per line in editpad.

Ex: Searching for number 1 in 947319949194 I only want the first 1 found, not the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe (in Perl) the first occurrence of `1` per line should be found by regex `/^[^1\n\r]*(1)/m`

Comment: Quick on the draw Omega, I was halfway through it.

Comment: @Ccorock - Multiline mode - see http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html

Comment: In EditPad, multiline mode is the default--you can't even turn it off like you can with other options.  (Why would you want to?)  You don't need regex delimiters, either.

Comment: @AlanMoore - Thank you for that information. Because I was not sure about EditPad defaults and syntax, I explicitely wrote in my answer that the solution is Perl regex.