# matching first occurrence of a symbol without anything else in EditPad

Tags: regex, select, match, highlight, editpad

There is a question like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647258/perl-regular-expression-for-finding-first-occurence-per-line-editpad) asking about the first occurrence of "1" in each line, but in EditPad it doesn't work at all, even when I use the Multi-Line Search Panel.

I have Regex on, Highlight All on. All other functions are off.

1. /^[^1\n\r]*(1)/m - highlights nothing
2. ^[^1\n\r]*(1)/m - highlights nothing
3. ^[^1\n\r]*(1) - finds all lines that contain "1" and highlights everything from the start of the line until the number "1". But I need only the first occurrence of "1", nothing else.

I guess that ^[^1\n\r]*(1) is one step towards the real "first occurrence", but it is not there yet.

For example, I have the number
5215681571

And I want to highlight only the first "1" in the line. The expression ^[^1\n\r]*(1) will highlight 521 which is not desirable.

I have tried also ^(^.*[^1])1 which finds every line that contains 1 and highlights everything from start until the last "1".

In stackoverflow, I have seen countless suggestions on how to achieve the first occurrence, but none of them works in EditPad. Any idea, please?

Comment: Not sure which [regex flavour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular-expression_engines#Language_features) does EditPad use. If it's PCRE, [`^.*?\K1`](https://regex101.com/r/unV87Z/1/) would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In the patterns that you tried, you use a capture group, preceded by a match.

If this is [the tool](https://www.editpadpro.com/manual.html#optionregex) the regex engine is `indicated as JGsoft V2` which [supports](https://www.regular-expressions.info/jgsoft.html#v2) using `\K` to forget what is matched so far.

Matching all except 1 or a carriage return or a newline:

```
^[^\r\n1]*\K1
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6wkQPm/1)

Or matching all except 1 and vertical whitespaces `\v`

```
^[^\v1]*\K1
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XVADQL/1)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @The fourth bird suggested, EditPad's JGSoft engine supports infinite lookbehind, which lets you do this (tested in EPP Pro 8.2.4):

```
(?<=^[^1\r\n]*)1
```

To catch any kind of weird unicode line breaks you can also use `[^\p{Zl}]` in place of `[^\r\n]`, yielding these two alternate versions:

```
^[^\p{Zl}1]*\K1
```

or

```
(?<=^[^1\p{Zl}]*)1
```